# Error al intentar ejecutar un archivo .Rmd (R Markdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown

Cuando intento ejecutar un archivo .Rmd, haciendo click en el botón "Knit", en R Studio, me aparece este error en la consola:

```
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  no fue posible abrir el archivo 'C:/Users/Jonathan LÃ³pez/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/evaluate/R/evaluate.rdb': No such file or directory

Calls: :: ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> registerS3methods -> get
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Pero como se puede observar el archivo sí existe. No sé si el problema sea que la ruta contiene caracteres especiales, en cuyo caso no sé cómo puedo solucionarlo.

[image: Como se puede observar el archivo sí existe]

El código que estoy ejecutando es la plantilla que se genera al crear un R Markdown, más unos datos en la cabecera:

````
---
title: "My First R Markdown"
author: "Jonathan López"
date: "12/05/2020"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código con el que estas intentando leer `evaluate.rdb`

Comment: Sí señor, ya lo agregué

Comment: Probá reinstalar `evaluate` así: `remove.packages("evaluate");
install.packages("evaluate")`

Comment: El problema persiste

Comment: Debes añadir la línea exacta dentro del ejemplo Markdown para poder ayudarte

Comment: Es que el error no me apunta a ninguna linea del ejemplo Markdown, me aparece tal cual lo especifico en la publicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola estuve investigando sobre lo que te sucede y parece que es un error que existía en la versión 1.2.1268. de Rstudio con el encoding motivo por lo que no encuentra la ruta ya que la busca de manera incorrecta, actualiza a una versión mas reciente y esto estará solucionado la otra manera de evitar este error es utilizar la función render() para desde código abrir el documento, la discusión de este error esta aqui (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4254)

Comment: He realizado lo que me aconsejaste, pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Hola, lo que sucede es que al momento de leer la ruta que mencionas no reconoce los caracteres que contienen acentos.En Rstudio en la parte superior donde dice Help selecciona about Rstudio te debe decir la versión que tienes, ¿que versión aparece?

Comment: Hola, cuando consulto la versión me sale 1.3.958. De antemano gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: También noté que en la carpeta Usuarios tengo dos directorios: Jonathan López, que es el directorio del usuario de mi sesión, y otro llamado Jonathan LÃ³pez, que es el que se ve en el path del error en R Studio, y este solo tiene un subdirectorio llamado.ssh. Además, el directorio Jonathan LÃ³pez aparece con la fecha de creación de hace 2 semanas, y yo no fuí el que lo creó.

Comment: Pareciera que R esta buscando la librería "evaluate" en una ruta donde no esta, el siguiente comando  `.libPaths() ` te va decir donde R la busca

Comment: Aquí se discute un poco al respecto [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages]

Comment: La ruta donde la busca es la correcta, pero parece que, estando "López" en ella, termina reemplazando la "ó" por "Ã³", por lo que termina yendo a buscar la biblioteca en otra ruta

Comment: un ejercicio interesante es copiar las librerías donde la están buscando mas que nada porque comentas que la ruta si existe, y ver si se puede ejecutar, se que no es una solución pero en teoría debería funcional

Comment: Lo que me recomendaste fue lo más conveniente, ahora no me arroja error. Muchas gracias.